# Controlling the preventDefault to select which default to prevent

Tags: javascript, html, events, preventdefault, stoppropagation

In a page I'm working on I have this HTML (simplified version; the original is a bit more complex).

```
<a href="alink.php" >
    <b>1</b>
    <span name="aName" data-editable="text" ></span>
    <span class="type">numeric</span>
</a>
```

Then I have a system that allows an "edit mode".
That edit to mode changes that HTML to this:

```
<a href="alink.php" >
    <b>1</b>
    <span name="aName" data-editable="text" ><input name="aName" type="text"></span><img src="ok.png"><img src="x.png"></span>
    <span class="type">numeric</span>
</a>
```

The issue is as follows:
When the user clicks the input how can I have the carret where the user clicked without anything else happening?

For that I tried this:
If I use the preventDefault(), the user is not sent to the link but the carret is also not positioned where the user clicked.
If I use stopPropagation(), nothing is prevented, the link is clicked.
If I use both, same as preventDefault() happens.

One possible solution I thought is to get rid of the `<a>` and replace it with a different tag, like a `<span>` tag. I just would prefer not to have to do that due to how this system works. If you think that there's a nice alternative, then please state it.

No examples or answers with libraries **please**

**Edit:** My relevant js code, as requested:

```
this.editableElement = document.createElement('input');
this.editableElement.type = "text";
this.editableElement.onclick = function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}.bind(this);
this.editableElement.name = this.parent.getAttribute('name');
this.editableElement.value = this.currentText;
```

**Edit2:** jsfiddle as requested.
http://jsfiddle.net/brunoais/gZU8C/

Now try to place the caret where you clicked. You'll check that the input becomes selected, the link is not followed but the caret is not placed where you clicked.

Comment: You'll need to provide the js code you're using or no one can help you with this. Usually you need to pass the object being clicked and call preventDefault on it, so it knows which one. That help?

Comment: @rncrtr If I do a preventDefault() it prevents the link from sending the user but also the input from setting the place to place the caret.

Comment: Using `stopPropagation()` **should work** - it depends on how you you're binding the event. As mcrtr said, post your actual JS code

Comment: @brunoais in your js code what is `this`? if you can show working demo of your problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com then i can help you

Comment: @rahulmaindargi Done. I sure hope you can help me with this :).

Comment: @brunoais for me in your new jsfiddle 'caret does show where I click it'..http://jsfiddle.net/brunoais/gZU8C/ I tried on chrome

Comment: @rahulmaindargi Could you please try it in firefox?